# COUNT values in a column and store count in variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried a few things and googled but can't get something that works. I want to use an SQL query to count how many rows in a table has "Rock" as it's value inside the "Genre" column. And then I need to store the count number inside a variable so that I can echo it later in my page. Any help? I'm new to php...

Answer (score 0):

A query like this

```
$lo_rec = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`genre`) as `total`
FROM `tablename`
WHERE `genre` = 'ROCK'");

$result = mysql_fetch_object($lo_rec);
```

Then when you grab the results, assign it

```
$li_count = $result->total;
echo $li_count;
```

And before anyone says so, I know to use mysqli or PDO :-)

Comment: *"And before anyone says so, I know to use mysqli or PDO"* - So why didn't you?